# Selecting all rows with dates in a unstructured csv

Tags: python, r, csv

So I have the output of a Google Trends query. It contains several tables on one sheet. The first part of the sheet looks like:

```
Web Search interest: nespresso  
United States; date_range:(today 90-d)  

Interest over time  
Day nespresso
8/7/2015    70
8/8/2015    82
8/9/2015    91
8/10/2015   84
```

So here's what I'd like to do. Disregard the first few rows and select any rows with a date. (weekly data from have date as 8/7/2015-8/14/2015). Sure, there's nrow and skip in read.csv, but I was wondering if there was a systematic way to do this.

Also, bear in mind that the data from Google trends includes data after the dates.

```
11/3/2015    
11/4/2015    


Top subregions for nes  
Subregion   nes
New York    100
Massachusetts   83
```

Looking for Python or R solution

Comment: This is what I did (though not in R): read it in; generate a `DF$tab <- cumsum(grepl("^Interest", DF$V1))` or similar to identify the several subtables; work in turn with the subset where `tab==1` and where `tab==2` and so on. The data has date ranges, not dates, so I don't know why you're showing the latter here...

Comment: Your output as displayed is not standard R output. Instead of manually entering the first few lines use `dput(head(mydata))`

Comment: Is this the file that we are looking at?

Comment: @Pierre Yes, it's non-standard. With that said, using fread on the google trends csv output does select the first table, so that is a solution.

Comment: @Richard, Yes, googel trends returns a csv with about four table on one sheet. Each is one top of each other with a few rows of separation.

Comment: This isn't a cvs file so using python's CSI reader would only get in the way. You could realizes until you see a line that starts with "Day" then read and process the lines with dates and break out of it when you see a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this Python solution to read in raw csv and convert first column to date. `Try/Except` is used to skip rows that do not convert properly to date format.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('Unstructured.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = []

    for row in csvReader:
        try:
            data.append([datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), row[1]])
        except ValueError:
            continue

    for i in data:
        print(i)
```

**Output** *(data list)*

```
['2015-08-07', '70']
['2015-08-08', '82']
['2015-08-09', '91']
['2015-08-10', '84']
['2015-11-03', '']
['2015-11-05', '']
```